# Is there any way to call instagram api without access token

Tags: javascript, android, ionic2, instagram-api

I am trying to call `https://www.instagram.com/"+username+"/?__a=1` but getting below error.

> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

But the URL is working on browser

Answer (score 0):

`?__a=1` method does not support `JSONP`, so you cannot make the API call client side, you can make http get request on server side.